# JavaScript | Create interval that changes a value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, setinterval

I have an array, a simplified form would be this:

```
let array = [
  {id: 1, value: 0}, 
  {id: 2, value: 0}, 
  {id: 3, value: 0}
];
```

Now I want to create an interval, that increments the value on the object with id: 3 every second.
What I would do now is target the object with 
`array[2].value`. This works as long as the array doesn't change.

The array I use is changing constantly, that means that elements get deleted/add in an asynchronous manner. When that happens the interval is pointing at the wrong element. If I would delete element [1] in the example, the interval would now point at an undefined element ([2]).

I was thinking of using an associative array (id as index), but in Angular ngFor does not work reliably anymore when I do that. Objects are also not working because of the same reason.

How can I create an interval that changes a property of an array element even when the index changes? Or is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: So you need to target key, instead index? Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9jqu6dhv/

Comment: This works. Do you have an explanation why? The code increments the value of the new array .filter created, but somehow the old array changes aswell? :o

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304383/javascript-return-reference-to-array-item "It returns a new array, but the array's entries are still references to the same objects."

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. This really has to be documented a bit more - no tutorial and not even the mozilla site explains this enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

```
function updateValue () {
   var item = array.find(item => item.id === 3)
   if (item) item.value++
}

setTimeout(updateValue, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly. Finally not stuck on this issue anymore! :D

Comment: Great! Since items in the array are objects, they will still update in the array even if referenced outside.

Answer (score 1):

You should hold a reference to the object, instead of using the index each time. For Example:

```js
let array = [
  {id: 1, value: 0}, 
  {id: 2, value: 0}, 
  {id: 3, value: 0}
];

function startIncrementing(elem) {
  setInterval(() => elem.value += 5, 500);
}

// Log the array every second
setInterval(() => console.log(array), 1000);

// Start the increment interval
startIncrementing(array[2]);

// Remove an elemnt after 1 second
setTimeout(() => array.splice(1, 1), 1000);
```